# TypeScript React Hooks Upgrade Path

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a TypeScript component with a few quirks, I'd love to translate them to a functional component and make use of the new React hooks.

I have private functions using Symbols,

A constructor and default props,

And a straightforward render function.

```
interface IProps {
  initialCount?: number;
}

interface IState {
  count: number;
}

const increment = Symbol();

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: props.initialCount!
    };
    this[increment] = this[increment].bind(this);
  }

  public static defaultProps = {
    initialCount: 0
  };

  [increment] = () => {
    const { count } = this.state;
    this.setState({ count: count + 1 });
  };
  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return( <>
      <p>I've been clicked {count} times!</p>
      <button
        onClick={this[increment]}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some small tips:

Defaulting props is way easier, you can drop that `!`

```
const Counter = ({ initialCount = 0 }: IProps) => //
```

We can add `useState` and `useEffect` to manage your state.

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });
}
```

Your function is privatised using closures, no need to mess with symbols!

```
const Counter () => {
  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1); 
  return (<div/>)
}
```

Put it all together and we get:

```
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import * as React from "react";
import "./style.css";

interface IProps {
  initialCount?: number;
}

const style: any = { backgroundColor: "blue" };

const Counter = ({ initialCount = 0 }: IProps) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(initialCount);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);

  return (
    <div className="byop-app__counter" style={style}>
      <Typography variant="h3">
        You clicked{" "}
        <span data-testid="byop-app__counter-count-value">{count}</span> times
      </Typography>

      <Button
        className="byop-app__counter-button"
        data-testid="byop-app__counter-button"
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={increment}>
        Click me
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```